# Have PHP count rows with a query that is already using count(*)?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a subquery and I want to count the rows in PHP for MySQL.  I am trying to fix old code and know that PDO is better and more secure and we will eventually rewrite all this code, but for now I need to just make it work.  My problem is figuring out the command for the $total_employees to count the rows.  This number will be used in a formula later.  Is there a way to do it as 2 subqueries or rewriting it in the SQL statement other than just using php and mysql_fetch_row?  I am trying to avoid multiple while loops.  This is condensed from a bigger query for easier viewing.

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($sqls)){
    $cycle_id = $rows[cycle_id];

    $sqls=("select subb.sqlcal AS sqlcalemp from 
    (select count(*) as sqlcal from  dialogue_employees d_e, 
    dialogue_leaders d_l where
    d_l.leader_group_id = d_e.leader_group_id and
    d_l.cycle_id = $cycle_id) as subb");

    $total_employees += $rows[sqlcalsemp];
```

This was the older code that worked before trying to update it:

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($sqls)){
    $cycle_id = $rows[cycle_id];
$sqlcalcemp=mysql_query("select count(*) from  dialogue_employees d_e, 
dialogue_leaders d_l where
d_l.leader_group_id = d_e.leader_group_id and
d_l.cycle_id = $cycle_id") or die(mysql_error());

$rowtotal = mysql_fetch_row($sqlcalcemp);
$total_employees += $rowtotal[0];
```

Comment: you subquery returns a single count..then your outer query selects this count which isn't needed. so you should only get one row back

Comment: show us the other query to get `cycle_id`, we might be able to join and/or count them and group by `cycle_id` and give you the result in one query so that you don't have to do multiple queries and the loop

Comment: and if possible, provide an sqlfiddle.com for some of your data for testing purposes that would be superb

Comment: I wasn't thinking about group by.  I might just use that.

Comment: check my answer, if you have a query before the query you posted that just grabs cycle_id ..then you can combine them like my anwer that will give you counts for each cycle_id then you can just loop through the result set without doing a query for each cycle_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your looping through and looking at each cycle_id...
maybe try something like this to grab all counts for each cycle_id at once

```
select SUM(d_e.leader_group_id IS NOT NULL) as sqlcalemp,d_l.cycle_id
from dialogue_leaders d_l
left join dialogue_employees d_e
on d_l.leader_group_id = d_e.leader_group_id
group by d_l.cycle_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4995b/4